# Matlab speed-up or get rid of loop with find function

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop

just struggleing a little bit with finding another way of implementation to get rid of this for-loop. Is there maybe a way to get rid of the slow for-loop? Thank you for your help!

```
list = randi(2000,[2000 1]);
val = randi(2000,[2000 3000]);

for ii = 1:length(list)
    [y,x] = find( val  == list(ii) );
    minx = min(x);
    maxx = max(x);

    minx1 = ceil(minx + 0.05 * (maxx - minx ));
    maxx2 = ceil(maxx - 0.02 * (maxx - minx ));
    val(y,minx:minx1) = 0;
    val(y,maxx2:maxx) = 0;
end
```

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve here in the output? But regardless, loops can be JIT compiled, and may be not be any/much slower than a vectorised solution?

Comment: @Justin want to split 'val' into seperated grids. Maybe there is a better to do this step :D.